# Load multiple obj and mtl in threebox

Tags: angular, web

I'm using threebox to load 3d model from pairs of .obj and .mtl files for 3d map. However, when load model with loadObj, it uses only the last mtl file to render img and color for all obj. How can I fix this.[When i add 3 obj it apply the third mtl for all 3 obj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4Bgm.png)[Correct obj1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnFVz.png)

I searched and found out that loadObj is an async func but I try await and even Promise but it didn't work.
Here is the code:

```
map: Map;
  path = '../assets/SG_NhaThoDucBa/';
  tb: any;

  coordList = [
    [106.693039, 10.772404],
    [106.6929226, 10.77202084],
    [106.6927602, 10.7712239],
    [106.6926045, 10.7703538],
    [106.692724, 10.770191],
    [106.6935564, 10.770271],
    [106.6935902, 10.7702023],
    [106.6936212, 10.770139],
    [106.6935586, 10.7696358],
    [106.693639, 10.768409],
  ];

  constructor() {}

  private buildMap(): void {
    this.map = new Map({
      container: 'map',
      zoom: 15.4,
      center: [106.693039, 10.772404],

      pitch: 64.9,
      bearing: 172.5,
      antialias: true,
      style:
        '../map.json',
    });
  }

  private addLayer(options: any, index: number): void {
    this.map.on('style.load', () => {
      const _this = this;
      this.map.addLayer({
        id: 'custom-threebox-model ' + index,
        type: 'custom',
        renderingMode: '3d',
        onAdd: function () {
          _this.tb.loadObj(options, (model: any) => {
            model.setCoords(_this.coordList[index]);
            model.setRotation({ x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 });
            _this.tb.add(model);
          });
        },

        render: function () {},
      });
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.buildMap();
    this.tb = (window as any).tb = new Threebox(
      this.map,
      this.map.getCanvas().getContext('webgl'),
      {
        defaultLights: true,
        enableSelectingObjects: true,
        enableDraggingObjects: true,
        enableTooltips: true,
        multiLayer: true,
      }
    );

    this.coordList.forEach((item, index) => {
      let i = index > 8 ? index + 1 : '0' + (index + 1);
      const options = {
        obj: this.path + i + '/0_anew_object.obj',
        mtl: this.path + i + '/autogenerate.mtl',
        type: 'mtl',
        scale: { x: 3.2, y: 3.2, z: 2.7 },
        units: 'meters',
        rotation: { x: 90, y: -90, z: 0 },
      };
      this.addLayer(options, index);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.